# What style of piano is used in The Gaithers' "One Day" (featuring Lynda Randle)

Tags: identify-this-genre, piano, live-music, style

[Lynda Randle: Some day Jesus will call my name](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHhoMfXgazw)

I kindly would like to know the name of the style used in piano in the song above. I have tried looking for jazz tutorials but they don't sound similar. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is gospel piano, a traditional style for religious music from the black American church that has a long and influential history, in parallel with secular black American musical styles such as jazz, the blues and soul.  Like other black American music, it has roots in traditional African musical styles.

However, there are many different kinds of gospel piano.  I would describe this as an "uptempo gospel blues piano".

This video is a [pretty close tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWDIO6_V9fs) for what you are looking for.  This video isn't as close a match, but gives more of [the theory and science](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ribnpn-ezYA) of this kind of music.  If you'd like to learn more of the [history and range of gospel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHItWFbU7-A), try this video.